# Why does Entity Framework overwrite my primary key and then throw a primary key violation exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am experiencing some strange behavior in Entity Framework.  I am looping through a list of non-entity "subcomponent" objects and inserting them into my database.  After retrieving and verifying that the parent Component entity exists, I instantiate a new SubComponent entity, assign a new Guid to the primary key field, wire it up to the parent Component entity, and then add it to the SubComponent entity set and save changes.

I have used this pattern elsewhere in my code without issue.  This time, though, when I call db.SaveChanges() it throws a primary key violation exception complaining that an entity with that key already exists in the database.  This is confusing to me since I have just created and assigned a new Guid for each SubComponent.  When I step through the code I find that the new Guid is indeed created and assigned at { obj.id = id }.  After the code executes { db.SubComponents.Add(obj) }, I observe that { obj.id } has somehow gotten reset to the id of one of the other SubComponent entities that was inserted previously and this, of course, causes { db.SaveChanges() } to throw the exception indicating a primary key violation.

```
foreach (var sub in list)
{
    using (var db = new MyEntities())
    {
        //try to retrieve the subcomponent's parent component
        var comp = (from c in db.Components
                where c.Equipment_ID == sub.EquipmentId && c.ComponentName == sub.ComponentName
                select c).FirstOrDefault();
        if (comp != null) //a check to make sure the parent Component exists to avoid a foreign key violation
        {
            Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
            SubComponent obj = new SubComponent();
            obj.id = id;
            obj.Component = comp; //connect the new SubComponent to it's parent Component entity

            //assign a bunch of other junk here
            obj.Size = sub.Size;
            obj.Weight = sub.Weight;
            //etc...

            db.SubComponents.Add(obj); //for some reason this sometimes overwrites obj.id with the id of a SubComponent that had been added earlier
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is, why/how does Entity Framework overwrite the id that I assigned to my new entity at the point the new entity is being added to the SubComponent entity set?  Has anyone else experienced this sort of strange behavior?

The primary key is very simple.  In the database it is simply a single uniqueidentifier field without any default constraints.

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_SubComponent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The associated entity key is simply a non-nullable Guid:
[image]

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Are you sure that the GUID hasn't been genereted automaticaly? Can you show us your primary key configuration?

Comment: Where would it be generated automatically?  There is no default constraint on the field in sql server to automatically create a new uniqueidentifier.  Does EF do this sometimes?  It's odd because I have been doing something like this throughout my code - assign the id in code, add it to the entityset, SaveChanges() and haven't encountered this before.  In the EF Model browser, when I look at the properties for the PK of this entity, it also has no default value assigned.